# re-size the width of div depending on browser's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a slideshow with pager and some buttons next to pager of slideshow ([here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nneb31i8acn9gjw/index.html?dl=0) is html page) which I am trying to make responsive.

The images I am fetching from database. So that are varying in number.

The problem is that pager/navigation of slideshow is fine for less number of images but becomes problematic for more images. Pager is overlapping the buttons which are next to it. as shown below:

For Desktop screen: 
[image]

For small screen: [image]

Below is the div structure

```
<div id="controls-wrapper" >
   <div id="controls">
         <div id="cycle-nav"><ul></ul></div> <!-- pager -->
   </div>
   <div class="button1" id="button1">
   <a href="#">button 1</a>
   </div>
   <div class="button2" id="button2">button 2</div>
   <div class="button3"><a href="#" target="_blank">button 3</a></div>
</div>
```

I am finding the solution other than `media queries` if possible. I tried by giving width in % to all div, by putting container div to above structure and giving it 100% width and height, by $(width).width() function. But not getting the solution.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/4epwc9wh/)

Is there any way to dynamically adjust the width of div depending on browser's screen size?

Comment: Hi. Can u add some css and a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: @ Dejan.S: i have attached the demo html page with css on the text **here** in the first line of my question.

Comment: Better to use jsfiddle and provide the css in the question. Most people don't want to download files.

Comment: @ Dejan.S: As question is relating to responsive, so I have attached html file. But now i have also added jsfiddle in my question.

Comment: use width in % not in pixels .

Comment: @ ris: i tried that with the arrow navigation. its working responsive but how can i apply width in % to above div structure to make it responsive? I tried it but not able to get proper responsive width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple solution using CSS and HTML, no @media queries no JavaScript,
I just modified some lines of HTML and CSS to your code those are below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="controls-wrapper" >
            <div id="controls">
            <div id="cycle-nav"><ul></ul></div>
            </div>
            <div class="buton-controls">
                <div class="button1" id="button1">
                <a href="#">button 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="button2" id="button2">button 2</div>
                <div class="button3"><a href="#" target="_blank">button 3</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**css**

```
/* I wanted to center my loader */
            #cycle-loader {
                height:32px;
                left:50%;
                margin:-8px 0 0 -8px;
                position:absolute;
                top:50%;
                width:32px;
                z-index:999;
            }

            /*I want to avoid jumpiness as the JS loads, so I initially hide my cycle*/
            #maximage {
                display:none;/* Only use this if you fade it in again after the images load */
                position:fixed !important;
            }


        #arrow_left, #arrow_right {
                bottom:45%;
                height:67px;
                position:fixed;
                right:3%;

                width:36px;
                z-index:1000;
            }
            #arrow_left {
                left:3%;
            }

            #arrow_left:hover, #arrow_right:hover {
                bottom:45%;
            }
            #arrow_left:active, #arrow_right:active {
                bottom:45%;
            }
            a {color:#666;text-decoration:none;}
            a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}

            /*I want to style my pager*/
#cycle-nav {
    /*    float:left;*/
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#cycle-nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 100%
}
#cycle-nav ul li {
/*    border:1px solid #FF8000;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin:3px;
}

#cycle-nav ul li a {
  /*background: #057c96;*/
    background: #49BED8;

    float:left;
    height:10px;
    margin:2px;
    width:10px;


}


#cycle-nav ul li a:hover {
        background: #000;
        opacity:0.6;

}

#cycle-nav ul li.activeSlide {
   /* border:1px solid #000;*/
/*   background: #075262;*/
    }

#cycle-nav ul li.activeSlide > a {
    background: #075262;
}
#controls-wrapper { margin:0 auto; height:42px; width:100%; bottom:70px; z-index:4; background:url(../img/nav-bg.png) repeat-x; position:fixed; }

#controls { width: 50%; float: left; }
.buton-controls{
    width: 50%; 
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.buton-controls > div{
    display: inline-block;
}
.button2{
    background-color: red;
    font: 14px/23px 'TitilliumText25L400wt',Arial,sans-serif;
    height: 20px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.button2:hover{
    background-color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:1 !important;
}

.button2hoverBg{
    background-color:#137087 !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:1;
}

.button3{
background-color: red;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font: 14px/23px 'TitilliumText25L400wt',Arial,sans-serif;
    height: 20px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 70px;\
}

.button3:hover, a:hover{
    background-color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:1 !important;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#FFFFFF;
}

.button3 a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
   text-decoration:none;

}


.button1{
    background-color: red;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font: 14px/23px 'TitilliumText25L600wt',Arial,sans-serif;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.button1 a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
   text-decoration:none;

}
```

Comment: when i applied above code is showing like this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwwz7yugw3sa3vx/answer.png?dl=0

Comment: @Kiran please check my answer now, I have updated it

Comment: @ Nilesh Mahajan: for smaller size, its fine. But getting more space between pager and buttons for desktop screen. when I was trying to solve problem with css, was facing this problem. Can both pager and buttons be center aligned for desktop screen size with proper space in between and not affecting the responsiveness? thanks.

Comment: @Kiran, Yes what you are expecting is also possible. you just need to change #cycle-nav {text-align:right} & .buton-controls {text-align:left;}

Comment: @ Nilesh Mahajan : It simply works great as I was expecting. Thanks a lot. there is little observation as i have made `#cycle-nav {text-align:right}`, the pager boxes starts from right when i add more images to it. as like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/vh2vz8nvhxaefhp/answer1.png?dl=0. Can it start from left?

Comment: Yes, It can start from left also, but then it will not be in the center for larger resolution devices such as Desktop, if you want to check how it looks simply change #cycle-nav {text-align:left}

Comment: @ Nilesh Mahajan: yaah, you are correct. for for desktop it is not look like in center as previous. then is it possible by any other way?

Comment: If you want to have different behaviors for different resolutions using CSS only, then I will suggest to go for @media queries

Answer (score 3):

You can use the @media queries. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: lightblue;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
                body {
                    background-color: lightgreen;
                }
            }
        </style>
     </head>
    <body>
     ...
</body>
</html>
```

This will change the background color of the body to lightblue. But when you resize your browser window to less than 300px it will change to lightgreen. I hope this will help you with your problem.

Comment: @ Aruloci: ok. I am guessing that you had suggested me to use media queries  by changing the css as I want, like this  ` @media screen and (max-width: 300px) { /*my css*/ }`. Am I guessing right? And one thing do I require to write css for all screen sizes? (which I was not thinking to use as it is time consuming, have to write css for all sizes )

Comment: @kiran If you want to change the size of a div when the device width is smaller than 500px you should do it something like this:
    ATmedia screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        .myDiv {
            width: 25px;
        }
    }

This will format the div width to 25px for all devices with a size of less than 500px.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `vw` and `vh` CSS properties.

1vw = 1% of window width, 
1vh = 1% of window height.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design

Comment: @ Jeremy Thille : Can you please explain me, how should I use `vw` and `vh` CSS properties to above div structure from the question ?  thanks.

Comment: Well, just like a regular width and height. Like, instead of `.someClass{ width : 50% }` or `.someClass{ width : 300px }` , just use `.someClass{ width : 30vw }` and it will be 30% of the window width.